# Docker container based on microsoft/aspnet can't load Kestrel

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core

I'm trying out all kind of new features of asp.net 5 and documenting it and now I hit the first obstacle. I can't get my code to run in a docker container, I'm not even trying to get the container to listen to changes, I just want it to run.

I've based my image on `microsoft/aspnet` and added code to install `node`, `npm`, `bower` and `grunt` so I can build the application in the container. I know I probably can build it in the client before I add it to the container, but I want to give this a try. The image builds fine, but when I start the container it can't find `Kestrel`.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Kestrel' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Kestrel'
  at System.AppDomain.Load (System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyRef, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:Load (System.Reflection.AssemblyName,System.Security.Policy.Evidence)
  at System.AppDomain.Load (System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyRef) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:Load (System.Reflection.AssemblyName)
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load (System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyRef) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Server.ServerLoader.LoadServerFactory (System.String serverFactoryIdentifier) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.HostingEngine.EnsureServerFactory (Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.HostingContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.HostingEngine.Start (Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.HostingContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Shouldn't `Kestrel` already exist since I base it on `microsoft/aspnet`?

The code to my Dockerfile: https://github.com/mastoj/OneManBlog/blob/master/src/OneManBlog/Dockerfile

Comment: Ignoring Dockery for the moment, can you get your web application to run with Kestrel directly on the OS?

Comment: I'm only using Windows but want to be able to run in the container as well. I don't have a "real" os to try on at the moment, but I could probably just set one up from the aspnet image and do it manually there.

Comment: @mason but it feels weird that any of my steps would have corrupted the kestrel part, I thought that was basically the purpose of the aspnet image.

Comment: When in doubt, isolate. So yes, run it on OS X or Linux first. You can obtain Linux and set it up in  Virtual Box VM pretty easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The microsoft/aspnet base image (https://github.com/aspnet/aspnet-docker/blob/master/1.0.0-beta4/Dockerfile) only gives you the minimum distro needed to run Kestrel, including dnvm and the latest dnx, but NOT Kestrel itself. Add the Kestrel NuGet package to the dependencies in your project.json and build the docker image again:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta4"
}
```

EDIT: Did a test on your repo and that made it work :)